# HTML site with AJAX request image onclick execute PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, onclick

I will really appreciate if you could help me in that coding. I really need help.
    I want with single press over the image, to get the data from fields sent over email.

So my HTML image code like that :

```
<img src="images/some.png" id="help" onClick="help();">
```

Right before that tag in HTML file I put AJAX like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function help() {
    $.get("/help.php");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

And with that function i want, when the user click over the image to execute my PHP script which is on other file and it contains code like that : 
    help.php

```
<?php
{
$helpSubject = 'help';
$webMaster = '****@mail.com';

$helpField = $_POST['help'];
$problemField = $_POST['problem'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Help: $help <br>
Problem: $problem <br>
EOD;

 $headers = "Reason: $help\r\n";
 $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
 $success = mail($webMaster, $helpSubject, $body, $headers);

$theResults = <<<EOD
Success
EOD;
echo "$theResults"; 
}
?>
```

Something is wrong, and I can't find what. Could anyone help me with that? 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help others to help you if you specify exactly what went wrong - i.e. what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: Thank you. Well since i used AJAX without refreshing page, when i click the image, nothing happaned. I mean, all the data from the fields should be sent over my email, but.. chasing dreams.. :/

Comment: Where you get the `$help` and `$problem` from?

Comment: This might be a typo in the small example you gave, but your "onclick" action in the HTML is calling a function `help()`, but your JS function is called `some()`

Comment: #J Richard Snape - It's the same function i just mistook.

Comment: #phillip100 - From a table fields.

Comment: Some issues: (1) you are not submitting any data with the AJAX request; (2)  you are using `GET`, yet listening to `POST` variables in your PHP script.

Comment: @absenttt , I guess that you want them from table fields :-) But I ask about variables: U set `$helpField` but you use `$help` later on. So, I ask where  `$help` and `$problem`  came from, where they are set in your PHP? Also, try to check what returns your  `$success` (should return true or false)

Comment: #Terry - How should look the submit data AJAX for that function in code? Also for (2), I though about that.. using POST instead of GET. I will try it.

Comment: #phillip100 - Well, they are the same objects in that PHP, i just abrv. them.

Comment: POST instead of GET .. still not working.

Comment: Anyone got some idea?

Comment: @absenttt in your variables `$help and $problem` what you want them to store. like `help` containes the ID of image clicked and `$problem` keeps the source of the image clicked.